# Stopping a Thread immediately whenever an Exception occurs within it

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

If an `Exception` occurs at some point in Java code, the control goes to the `catch` block. However, If this code is actually inside a multi-threaded `run()` method, how do I instruct the code the to finish with the `run()` method when the `Exception` occurs?

In other words, how can I instruct the thread that the `run()` method has finished, because it knows that an `Exception` has occurred?

Comment: seems like you miss some part of the question...

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail about both what you want to have happen, what's actually happening, etc. And of course, code is worth a thousand words. This question can't reasonably be answered in its current form.

Comment: This question is clearly unfinished.

Comment: The edit remains vague, but I've taken a stab at it. The more effort you put into the question, the better both the quality and quantity of the responses you'll get.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the `run()` method of your `Thread`, you can simply `return`, which terminates the `Thread` in the same way that calling `return` in any other method ends the method processing.

Maybe something like this, where you watch for an `Exception` and call `return` if the `Exception` occurs...

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // your code goes here
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

However, if your `Thread` has multiple methods, the best way might be to have each method declare that it can throw an `Exception`. For example, if your `Thread` is like this...

```
public MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        try {
            runLongTask1();
            runLongTask2();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void runLongTask1() throws Exception {
        // your code here
    }

    public void runLongTask2() throws Exception {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

See how each of the other methods can throw an `Exception`. So, if an `Exception` is thrown in any of the methods of this `Thread`, it will trigger the `try-catch` of the `run()` method, and `return` out of the `Thread`, thus terminating it.

Of course, if the `try-catch` in your `run()` method covers all the code of the method, you don't need to actually `return`, because it is implicit when it reaches the end of the `run()` method anyway.

Comment: Do you happen to know if some exceptions forces a thread to exit even though I am catching them?

Answer (score 4):

> ...how do I instruct the code the to finish off with the run() method when this exception occurs, .i.e how can the code automatically instruct the thread that the run() method has finished, because it knows that an exception has occurred?

If I'm understanding you correctly, have the code in the `catch` block `return` or set a termination condition. That terminates the thread.

There are a couple of scenarios:

If you're using an outer `try/catch`, no explicit `return` is needed:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        while (!someExitCondition) {
            doSomethingUseful();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        doSomethingWithTheException(e);
        // Just falling through ends the thread, because
        // `run` returns
    }
}
```

If you're using an inner `try/catch`, you might use an explicit `return` or (probably better) set your termination condition:

```
public void run() {

    while (!someExitCondition) {
        try {
            doSomethingUseful();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            doSomethingWithTheException(e);
            return; // Terminates the thread; alternately, set a termination condition
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do I write in the doSomethingWithTheException code?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar: That's just a placeholder line for code that deals with the exception. What you should do with the exception totally depends on what your code does and how it should respond to an exception.